# Laravel 5.6.3 working in PHP 7.0

Tags: php, laravel

I just code an entire website in laravel 5.6.3 that needs at least PHP 7.1, but my server is limited to PHP 7.0.

Can I change the version of laravel without coding it all again?

Comment: Maybe just look into changing hosts..

Comment: There's no official downgrade guides for Laravel, but you could try to reverse the upgrade guide for 5.5.   It's likely not worth the effort unless there's some major reason you can't use PHP 7.1.

Comment: Try to revert Laravel version in your `composer.json` to lower version, run `composer update` and see what happens.

Comment: Unless you're using shared hosting there's no way you cannot upgrade php to 7.1. What are you using for hosting?

Comment: You can try installing lower version of laravel on the new server, and just copy the routes/views/controllers to their appropriate directories. Shouldn't take more than 30 minutes, I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your host or downgrade your Laravel project by just change the your `composer.json` file with the desired version and use the supported dependency for that version.

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work. It keeps complaining about the version 
"This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.31) does not satisfy that requirement."

Comment: @Richard do you add the good version for all the dependencies ? if yes, can you share cmd to us ?

Comment: I got it to work, I kept doing composer install on a current project, so instead I just deleted the lock file and did composer update and it works now.